# Grant select on all synonyms of schema to another schema in Oracle

Tags: oracle, permissions

I need to write a query for granting the select privilege to all synonyms and tables of one schema to another schema in Oracle.

#### Example:

`Admin` schema has all the tables. I want the `User` schema to access all the tables owned by `Admin`. So I want to grant select privilege to `User`. How can I write a query to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the script to generate grant select on all the tables and synonyms.

```
select 'grant select on Admin.' || object_name || ' to User;' 
from user_objects 
where object_type in('TABLE','SYNONYM');
```

Then you have to create a script to run these grant statements at once or you can use PL/SQL as well. Type the following in the SQL prompt.

```
SQL> spool grant_statements.sql
SQL> set pagesize 0
SQL> set feedback off
SQL> set linesize 300
SQL> set trimout on
SQL> set trimspool on
SQL> select 'grant select on Admin.' || object_name || ' to User;' from user_objects where object_type in('TABLE','SYNONYM')
/
SQL> spool off
```

And you have got the script file you can run it.
**OR** 
You can run the following PL/SQL block (Run as admin user).

```
BEGIN
  FOR s IN (SELECT *
              FROM user_objects where object_type in('TABLE','SYNONYM'))
  LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE  'grant select on admin.' || s.object_name || ' to user';
  END LOOP;
END;
```